# No removal of null values (Python)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, null

For processing the content of multiple CSV files, I have to filter several characters, most notably NULL values, from string-list-elements. For this I've tried several solutions from the web. One of them is the following function:

```
def removeNull(rawString):
    l = filter("\u0000", list(rawString))
    newString = ''.join(l)
    printUtil.printAll(newString, "\n")
    return newString
```

However, it always gives me `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`, terminating the program. The more sophisticated solutions didn't gave me an error but they changed absolutely nothing and the NULL values where still in place.

Furthermore, if I exchange `\u0000` by any other value but `None` (which results in no changes), I am getting the same error message.

Hopefully, someone can solve this for me for I am out of ideas after 4 or 5 hours of trial and error.

Thank you for your answers and suggestions!

**Solving the problem:**

The error message originated from the fact, that I used `"\u0000"` as argument for the build in filter-function. Two valid solutions to that particular problem focus on passing the necessary function:

```
l = filter(lambda x: x != '\u0000',rawString)
```

or

```
l = filter(lambda x:ord(x) != 0, list(rawString))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` expects the first argument to be a *function* (or, more precisely a `callable`).  It then iterates over the second argument, passing each to the function.  Where the function returns a False-like value, it is skipped in the output.

You could try:

```
l = filter(lambda x: x != '\u0000',rawString)
```

Comment: This removes the null-values. However, for the given input it returns gibberish afterwards. I have no idea why writing the filtered content of the file is totally different from the original and from the console ouput when only null-values should be deleted. I can upload my in- and output files if needed to make it more clear what happened. Edit: The same goes for Joran Beasleys solution.

Comment: For some clarification: The string which goes into the removal function behaves like a byte-array when saving it to a file, at least i have to go into binary writing mode. Unfortunately I do not understand this outcome too well but at least it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = filter(lambda x:ord(x) != 0, list(rawString))
```

should work better

to make it more transparent

```
def is_not_null(ch):
    return ch != u'\u0000'

print filter(is_not_null,list(rawString))
```

Comment: The result appears to be correct in the console window, however there are unexpected problems when saving this to a file (see my respont to the solution of mgilson).

Comment: I will have to look into that later. Thanks to both of you the final solution might be near.